# "Use of unassigned local variable" error C#, "while" command

Tags: c#, while-loop

While writing my code, I received this error for a,b and c.

```
           while(n==0)
        {
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            n=CheckTriang(a, b, c, n);

        }

        x=RightTriang(a, b, c, x);
```

I input a, b and c's values in the loop, then check them in the working method CheckTriang (determining if the values can make a valid triangle), and break the condition, returning n=1.
I think that the problem might be with the compiler not being sure if the loop will even stop to give the values. How can I rewrite the code to be clearer?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I only copied the problematic part, not the whole code. The needed variables are declared.

Comment: can we see the part where you define and initialize a,b,c and n?

Comment: Can you please post a working example so that we can test your code?

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to x? Your very last line tries to use a value named x but as far as we can tell it has no value. Set some break points and step through your code line by line. Verify everything has a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch to a do-while loop:

```
do {
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        n=CheckTriang(a, b, c, n);
    } while (n == 0)
```

This guarantees that you'll get through the loop at least once.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if `n==0` on the first run `a,b,c,& n` would never be initialized.  The compiler is catching this and warning you as such.  Simply add

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0, n=0;
```

somewhere above your while loop

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, when you declare `n`, that you initialize it:

```
int n = 0; // Add the = 0
```

Comment: Structs are initialized with their default values though. So `int n = 0;` is the same as `int n;`

Comment: The error is for a, b and c, everything else is working fine. I only copied a specific part. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @therealtbs While its true the value will be zero, and you could dynamically access it at run time, you'll have compile problems if you try compiling something like `int n; bool x = n == 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variables by indicating their type, and also initialize `n` before you use it.

```
int n = 0;
while(n == 0)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    n = CheckTriang(a, b, c, n);
}

//replace 'var' by whichever type 'RightTriang' returns.
var x = RightTriang(a, b, c, x);
```